# How do I create a rule with firewalld that uses a host name

Tags: linux, hostname, firewalld, source

I want to create a rule using firewalld on Linux (RHEL 7) to allow ssh from a host name. I think I've got figured out how to do it using an IP address but I need to use a host name. Here is the rule I've got so far.

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule=' rule family="ipv4"  source address="1.2.3.4" port protocol="tcp" port="22" accept'

I need something like:

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule=' rule family="ipv4"  source address="host.domainname.com" port protocol="tcp" port="22" accept'

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Well, no sooner than I post my question, I find, what I believe to be, the answer. Here is a link to what I found:  https://serverfault.com/questions/936415/reject-hostnot-ip-using-firewalld-firewalld-richlanguage